# MudBlazor menu not working on responsive mode

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, mudblazor

I'm trying to create a second menu, aligned at the right side of the top bar, but it's not working in responsive mode. I'm using MudBlazor 6.0.6 in a .NET6 Blazor server project
Here is the MudLayout I use:

```
<MudThemeProvider />
<MudDialogProvider />
<MudSnackbarProvider />

<MudLayout>
    <MudAppBar Elevation="1">
        <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Menu" Color="Color.Inherit" Edge="Edge.Start" OnClick="@((e) => DrawerToggle())" />
        <MudText Typo="Typo.h5" Class="ml-3">My Application</MudText>
        <MudSpacer />
        <MudMenu Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.MoreVert" Color="Color.Inherit" AnchorOrigin="@AnchorOrigin" TransformOrigin="@TransformOrigin">
            <MudMenuItem OnClick="@LoginHandler">Login</MudMenuItem>
            @*<MudMenuItem>My account</MudMenuItem>*@
            <MudMenuItem OnClick="@LogoutHandler">Logout</MudMenuItem>
        </MudMenu>

    </MudAppBar>
    <MudDrawer @bind-Open="_drawerOpen" ClipMode="DrawerClipMode.Always" Elevation="2">
        <NavMenu />
    </MudDrawer>
    <MudMainContent>
        <MudContainer MaxWidth="MaxWidth.ExtraExtraLarge">
            
                    @Body
               
        </MudContainer>
    </MudMainContent>
</MudLayout>
```

Does anyone know how to deal with this issue? Thanks.

Comment: try https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/issues/4549
adding OnTouch event handler (similar issue was resolved on my side)

Comment: I'm having the same issue with MudBlazor 6.0.14. Have you been able to solve this?

Comment: Same issue in version 6.1.7

Answer (score 0):

It fixed with last release. Please use 6.0.10

EDIT:
https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/pull/6358
This merged PR should solve the problem and will come with next release. (6.0.10)

Comment: Still not fixed with 6.0.14. Only with OnTouch it seems to be working.